# How to obtain a list of strings such that it represents all the strings in a given list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings.  From this list i want to generate a new list of strings such that all the strings are unique (i know i can use the `set` to do this), but this new list should be such that no string in the new list can be subset of any other string in the list.

EDIT
From the comments that i have received, i will try to put up some clarifications.  The word "subset" is not accurate, it should be *substring*.

Comment: This is going to be extremely computationally expensive.

Comment: Give such a list please.

Comment: I agree.  Computational power is not limiting.  But i cannot understand how to go about it.

Comment: How do you define subset in the context of strings? Do you mean substring? Or subset of words?

Comment: So from a list A of strings you want to create a list B of strings that are unique and no element of B is also in A?

Comment: @ZackBloom Your point is valid, and i have added the correction.

Comment: @Hunter How do you want to extract elements of a list A to put them in a list B of which no elements will be in A ???

Comment: @Sam It is whished you to clarify if you meant _"no string in the new list can be subset of any other string in the ORIGINAL list"_ or _"in the RESULTING list"_

Comment: @Sam: Please also clarify whether you mean that the new list must be the LONGEST qualifying list. For example, boat+man qualifies on both the ORIGINAL and RESULTING criterion, but boat+man+catamaran is longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alist = ['a', 'man', 'ran', 'at', 'a', 'catamaran', 'boat']
result = set()
for word1 in alist:
    if word1 in result:
        continue # shortcut for performance reasons only
    to_remove = []
    for word2 in result:
        if word1 in word2:
            break
        if word2 in word1:
            to_remove.append(word2)
    else:
        result.add(word1)
    for word in to_remove:
        result.remove(word)
print result
```

gives

```
set(['catamaran', 'boat', 'man'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
def unique_sublist(lst):
    sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=len, reverse=True)
    subs = set()
    result = []
    for s in sorted_lst:
        if s not in subs:
            subs.update(s[i:j] for i in range(0, len(s))
                        for j in range(i+1, len(s)+1))
            result.append(s)
    return sorted(result, key=lst.index)

>>> unique_sublist(['a', 'man', 'ran', 'at', 'a', 'catamaran', 'boat'])
['man', 'catamaran', 'boat']

>>> unique_sublist(['abcd', 'abyet', 'abcd betry', 'outry', 'rumunu abyetin', 'takama eli', 'com betry', 'rumunu', 'foutrym'])
['abcd betry', 'rumunu abyetin', 'takama eli', 'com betry', 'foutrym']
```

My edit fixes a few issues with the previous code.  Note that this now prefers longer words over shorter ones.

Comment: Fine. But your use of sorting subrepticely introduces an additional criteria. The list ['man', 'ran', 'boat'] is a valid one according the wording in the question. Why is **'catamaran'** authorized to be in the result in your code and not **'ran'** ? Because of the sorting

Comment: @eyquem:  You believe your reading is the correct one.  It appears F.J and I disagree with you.  It's a moot point because the OP has not clarified.  I don't think anyone needs to win this argument.

Comment: @Steven If I believe that my reading of the question is the correct one ? No. In fact, I don't know what to think now that FJ has shown that my answer is unsufficient. I also think it's useless to debate about an incomplete question. The problem seems to be harder than as simply it has been exposed. Need to be droped for the moment, yes.

Answer (score 2):

This simple code:

```
def funky(alist):
    result = []
    for s in sorted(alist, key=len, reverse=True):
        if not any(s in item for item in result):
            result.append(s)
    return result # no ordering requirement was specified

print funky(['a', 'man', 'ran', 'at', 'a', 'catamaran', 'boat'])
print funky(['abcd', 'abyet', 'abcd betry', 'outry', 'rumunu abyetin', 'takama eli', 'com betry', 'rumunu', 'foutrym'])
```

produces:

```
['catamaran', 'boat', 'man']
['rumunu abyetin', 'abcd betry', 'takama eli', 'com betry', 'foutrym']
```

Comment: +1.  Although mine runs slightly faster than yours it's not worth it. Simple really is best.

Answer (score 1):

I think it does it:

```
li = [ 'abcd',
       'abyet',
       'abcd betry',
       'outry',
       'rumunu abyetin',
       'takama eli',
       'com betry',
       'rumunu',
       'foutrym']


la = []
for x in li:
    if not any(x in el or el in x for el in la):
        la.append(x)

print li
print
print la
```

result

```
['abcd', 'abyet', 'abcd betry', 'outry', 'rumunu abyetin', 'takama eli', 'com betry', 'rumunu', 'foutrym']

['abcd', 'abyet', 'outry', 'takama eli', 'com betry', 'rumunu']
```

**PS**

But if 'abyet' and 'rumunu abyetin' are interchanged in the former list, the deducted list wil have 'rumunu abyetin' and not 'abyet'.
Why is 'abyet' authorized to be in the deducted list in the first case and not in the second ? : because of its place in the first list.

You must precise additional criteria to accept or refuse a string in the resulting list, because for the moment it seems to me that there are several combinations that can respond to your question from a given list

.

### PS

This answer of mine clearly doesn't deserve an upvote.
The upvoter is kindly asked to remove his upvote

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that `'abcd betry'` should have survived over `'abcd'`.

Comment: @Steven I don't think so., If 'abcd' and 'abcd betry' would remain in the complete resulting list, there would be a string , 'abcd' , that would be a substring of another string, 'abcd betry', which is the contrary of _"no string in the new list can be subset of any other string in the list"_

Comment: @eqyuem:  Which means to me that once you encounter 'abcd betry' you would *remove* 'abcd'.

Comment: @Steven Oh yes, you're right. That means that my code lacks the deleting of **'abcd'** from **la** when the string **'abcd betry'** is treated. But the fact is that the list **la** I obtain in my answer fulfills the requirements in the question, I believe. Then I think still more that there are not enough criteria given to obtain a unique list. For the moment, following the wording of the question, it seems that several combinations of elements from starting list are possible. In his answer, FJ subrepticely introduces an additional criterium

Comment: In this snippet from the question *"no string in the new list can be subset of any other string in the list"* what is the antecedent of "the list"?  Is it the new list or the original list?  I think it's the original list and you think the new list.  Which is why my original comment said "My *interpretation* ...".

Comment: @Steven Oh I understand now . If list means the original list, you are right, 'abcd' can't remain but 'abcd betry' is authorized